# Undefined control sequence error in \cite

Tags: bibtex, citing

```
 \documentclass{aa}  
    \begin{document}
 Most ordinary chondrites have lower coercivity than their main constituent ferromagnetic phases (\‍‍‍cite{gattacceca2003magnetic}). Different meteorites have significantly different magnetic properties. The coercivity of different meteorite classes is 1.78 mT for H chondrites, 5.62 mT for L chondrites and 36.40 mT  for LL chondrites.  This is true that LL chondrites have higher coercivity than L and H chondrites, because of increasing Fe content of the silicates from H to LL chondrites (\‍‍‍‍cite{gattacceca2003magnetic}). 

    \‍‍‍‍end{document}
```

the bibtex:

```
@article{gattacceca2003magnetic,
  title={Magnetic properties of a freshly fallen LL ordinary chondrite: the Bensour meteorite},
  author={Gattacceca, J{\'e}r{\^o}me and Rochette, Pierre and Bourot-Denise, Mich{\`e}le},
  journal={Physics of the Earth and Planetary Interiors},
  volume={140},
  number={4},
  pages={343--358},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.296 ...main constituent ferromagnetic phases (\�
                                                  ��‍‍cite{gattacceca200...
```

Comment: You have some weird invisible characters (zero-width joiners) in `(\‍‍‍cite{gattacceca2003magnetic})` specifically between the backslash and the `c` of `cite`. Delete that bit and re-type it.

Comment: @moewe I did. But still the error exists.

Comment: Did you do that for all occurrences of the error? In your example there are two `\cite`s and both contain invisible characters: The first three, the second four. Copy and paste your text to https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html and search for `U+200d` or `zero width`. (*edit*: The `\end{document}` *also* contains unwanted zero-width joiners.)

Comment: To get rid of the weird character �, as @moewe points out, you can (1) "Cut" the text ferromagnetic phases (\‍‍‍cite{gattacceca2003magnetic}).` from your line 296 of your tex file, (2) "Paste" it on some minimal text editor like Notepad in Windows (or browser address/search bar), (3) remove any unusual character like � or anything that you between `\` and `cite`, (4) "Copy" that text again, and (5) "Paste" it back to your tex file.  In that way you will be able to **see** what went wrong... and hopefully surpass that error.